# openldap fails to bind ldaps://127.0.0.1:636

Tags: centos, openldap

Here is my testcase :

> [root@192.168.121.130 ~$]slapd -d 1 -h  ldaps://127.0.0.1:636
>   @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.23 (Apr 29 2013 07:47:08) $
>           mockbuild@c6b7.bsys.dev.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.23/openldap-2.4.23/build-servers/servers/slapd
>   ldap_pvt_gethostbyname_a: host=centos-6.3, r=0
>   daemon_init: listen on ldaps://127.0.0.1:636
>   daemon_init: 1 listeners to open...
>   ldap_url_parse_ext(ldaps://127.0.0.1:636)
>   daemon: bind(7) failed errno=98 (Address already in use)
>   slap_open_listener: failed on ldaps://127.0.0.1:636
>   slapd stopped.
>   connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.

But if I change another port , such as `6361`, it works.

My environment:

> OS: centos 6.4 x86_64
>   OpenLDAP:   2.4.23  installed by yum

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that another service is already running on port 636:

```
daemon: bind(7) failed errno=98 (Address already in use)
```

you can try the following command to identify this service:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep ':636 ' | grep 'LISTEN'
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but still ...

This error is also displayed when SELinux prevents slapd from starting. Personally I experienced this after manually copying data (/var/lib/ldap/) from another server, to this one. I had to restore the imported files to default SELinux security contexts:

```
restorecon -R /var/lib/ldap
```

And I see this doesn't apply to you, but this *might* also happen if you're attempting to bind slapd to a port out of the ordinary. Default on CentOS7, these are the allowed ports:

```
#semanage port -l | grep ldap
ldap_port_t                    tcp      389, 636, 3268, 7389
ldap_port_t                    udp      389, 636
```

Adding another one to the legal port range, could be done with *semanage*. (You might need to install the package *policycoreutils-python*.):

```
semanage port -a -t ldap_port_t -p tcp 10389
```

... if you wish to allow slapd to bind on TCP port 10389 in addition to the four listed above. After this, the previous result would look like:

```
# semanage port -l | grep ldap
ldap_port_t                    tcp      10389, 389, 636, 3268, 7389
ldap_port_t                    udp      389, 636
```